# JavaFX custom list cell with button: handler not called

Tags: java, event-handling, javafx, handler, handle

I have a ListView to show some information, and I created a custom CellFactory: each cell has a label, an image and a small button. I want the user to be able to remove a list row by clicking on that small button.

The list is displayed correctly, but the handler associated to the button is never called...

```
public class ListViewCell extends ListCell<SessionExercise> {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(SessionExercise exercise, boolean empty) {

    ...

    FXMLLoader listItemLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    listItemLoader.setLocation(getClass().
        getResource("/view/SimpleExerciseListItem.fxml"));

    try {
        listItemLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    SimpleExerciseListItemController listItemController
            = (SimpleExerciseListItemController) listItemLoader.getController();

    ...

    this.setGraphic(listItemController.getAnchorPane());
}
```

And in my SimpleExerciseListItemController class:

```
public class SimpleExerciseListItemController implements Initializable {
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        btnRemove.
            setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("You clicked the remove button!");

                ...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've also tried setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler()) instead of setOnAction(new EventHandler()), but nothing is printed to the console...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-35864) which is fixed in the latest version.

The way you are implementing your `ListCell` is not a recommended approach; using the recommended approach also provides a workaround for the bug.

The issue is one of performance. For a given `ListView`, relatively few cells are created, but the `updateItem(...)` method may be called many times. (Arguably, in some cases, more times then is necessary, but the basic, intentional, design is that `updateItem(...)` can be called very frequently.)

So you should load your fxml file in the constructor only; manipulate it and set the graphic in the `updateItem(...)` method:

```
public class ListViewCell extends ListCell<SessionExercise> {

    private final SimpleExerciseListItemController listItemController ;

    public ListViewCell() {
        FXMLLoader listItemLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        listItemLoader.setLocation(getClass().
            getResource("/view/SimpleExerciseListItem.fxml"));

        try {
            listItemLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        SimpleExerciseListItemController listItemController
                = (SimpleExerciseListItemController) listItemLoader.getController();

        }
        @Override
        public void updateItem(SessionExercise exercise, boolean empty) {
            // don't omit this!!!
            super.updateItem(exercise, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                // update controller and ui as necessary

                this.setGraphic(listItemController.getAnchorPane());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks!
I also changed the code according to your suggestions :-)